# Error with composer.phar installing Zend Framework Skeleton App

Tags: php, wampserver, zend-framework2, composer-php

I have searched basically everywhere I could think of and can't find anyone with the particular problem I'm running into.  I'm still back in the bronze age on XP x64, running WAMP.  I can get through the install process until the following point:

```
php composer.phar install
```

At which point we get the following output:

> 'mode' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined offset: 4' in phar://C:/wamp/www/zf2-tutorial/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:852

Followed by a stacktrace.

As far as I can tell I have a bog-standard WAMP install and my PATH is configured properly.  Any advice?

Comment: have you tried updating the composer.phar file with the latest install?

Comment: Which version of PHP do you have installed?

Comment: yea, I ran self-update prior to install.  I'm running PHP 5.3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by manually writing a composer.json file for a different project and using it to load [Doctrine](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule) of all things.  Since then I have been able to run install without any similar errors.  Not sure why this fixed the issue but I recommend anyone having a similar problem try it.

Below is the JSON I used for Doctrine:

```
{
"name": "My/Project",
"require": {
    "doctrine/common": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/orm": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/dbal": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-module": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master"
},
"authors": [
    {
        ...
    }
]
}
```